# How do you update all the values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, processing

I am using processing, and I have a HashMap, in which I want to be able to increment all the values by 1.
The code looks like this:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> keyStates = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

void press(Character k) {
  keyStates.put(k, 1);
}

void release(Character k) {
  keyStates.put(k, 0);
}
```

And the Integer tells me how long I have been pressing a key. Thus, I want to increment all the values of this HashMap by one, regardless of key, every "tick" or frame. Is there a way to increment all Integer Values of a HashMap, or, if not, another way of getting around this issue. Thank you very much for your help. Also, this is my first post, so please tell me if I am doing it right.

Comment: Store the "start_frame", then you can do "now_frame - start_frame" to determine how long the press was.

Comment: Or iterate and increment each value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, user3618302!  As far as I know, your only choice to do what you are asking is to follow Dave's advice above, and iterate, increment, and set again.  However, user2864740's advice is also quite helpful, and will likely save you a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Wow thank you so much user28 whatever. This is my first post, and this website sure is good! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it would be by using Iterator :

```
  Iterator<Map.Entry <Character, Integer> > it = keyStates.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry<Character, Integer> pair = it.next();
      Integer newCount = (pair.getValue() == null) ? 1 : pair.getValue() + 1 ;
      pair.setValue(newCount);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I found a much simpler solution to my problem in paticular, but this will come in handy another time :)